# Prefixes in haskell

Tags: haskell

I've written 2 functions in haskell, and now i have to write a third one, for calculating the number of prefixes in haskell. here's an example:

i have to lists. the first is the prefixes list, and the other one is the text list. what this function is suppose to do, is to calculate the number of times each word from the prefix list is a prefix of all the words in the text list, and present it in a tuple (word, number of times it appears as a prefix in the text words:

prefix list ["go", "co"]

text list ["golf", "company", "count"]

this should return [("go", 1) , ("co", 2)]

i have this:

```
isPrefixOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
isPrefixOf [] _ = True
isPrefixOf _ [] = False
isPrefixOf (x:xs) (y:ys) = x == y  && isPrefixOf xs ys


prefixCount :: (Eq a1, Num a) => [a1] -> [[a1]] -> a
prefixCount _ [] = 0
prefixCount x (y:ys) | isPrefixOf x y = 1 + prefixCount x ys
                 | otherwise = prefixCount x ys


howManyPrefixes [] _ = error("empty list!")
howManyPrefixes (x:xs) y  = map (\x -> (x,prefixCount x y)) xs
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete

Comment: You have name shadowing in the mapped function which makes it difficult to understand what the goal of the function is.

Comment: yan may be referring to the lack of type signature for howManyPrefixes. Is this intentional?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson i've edited it now, and i explained what it's suppose to do, for better understanding

Comment: @fauxCoder i've edited it, so you can understand it better

Comment: You still have shadowing, but it's more clear what you want. There isn't actually a need for recursion if you use `map`, though: `howMany xs y = map (\x -> (x, prefixCount x y)) xs`. Notice how in this version it's always clear what `x` refers to---it only exists in the inner function.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I understand, but i need to make a recursive function for it, because i'm studying it and i'm not understanding it very well.. I managed to write the previous two, but i'm having a hard time with this one.. i think i'm pretty close though. Can you help me doing it recursively?

Comment: Yup, try `howMany (x:xs) y = let count = prefixCount x y in (x, count) : howMany xs y`. The let binding lets you "unnest" the values and recur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive definition would be

```
howManyPrefixes :: [[a]] -> [a] -> [([a], Int)]
howManyPrefixes [] _     = []
howManyPrefixes (x:xs) y = 
  let count = prefixCount x y 
  in (x, count) : howManyPrefixes xs y
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use map, which is still recursive of course:

```
howManyPrefixes prefixList wordList = 
    map (\prefix -> (prefix, prefixCount prefix wordList)) prefixList
```

If you really want to do it without using `map` then you can just re-implement `map` like with anything else. `map` is just:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

So you can transform the above into:

```
howManyPrefixes [] _ = []
howManyPrefixes (prefix:prefixList) wordList = 
 -- f x                                   : map f xs
    (prefix, prefixCount prefix wordList) : howManyPrefixes prefixList wordList
```

Comment: But if i wanted a recursive solution, how would that be like ?